# SPI header File

Tags: c, embedded, pic, spi, interfacing

I require the SPI header file so I may write a SPI master and slave for two PIC24FJ64GA002. I had one but I accidentally deleted it. Please may some one send me a link to download the header. As soon as possible as it is urgent.

Comment: How about just reinstall the tools. It only takes a few minutes.

Comment: Are you talking about the Microchip peripheral library that comes with the C32 toolsuite?

Answer (score 5):

You say "the SPI header" as if there was one definitive such header, but this may have been a header that you or someone in your team or company created, it may have been provided as part of your compiler tool-chain, or by the chip vendor, or by a third-party.

There is no "one SPI header", so you will have to give us more information.

Moreover, the header alone would not provide the object code necessary to implement an SPI driver; headers generally simply *declare* functions provided by some library, object or source code to be compiled and/or linked to your code later in the build process.  So you will specifically need the header that is associated with whatever library code you are using.

There is a PIC24 library available at http://www.reesemicro.com/ that includes SPI support. Microchip have an [application note](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en527719) on interfacing EEPROM with SPI that you could probably adapt to your purposes.

Comment: Yoy have been very helpfull. Thank you very much, its actually for my final year project.